# Why can height 100% not be applied in my div?

Tags: html, css, bulma

Can someone explain me why the height of `div.project-desc` (child of `div.project`) does not occupy the `100%` of its container when `div.project` is hovered? This occurs when the viewport width is less than `769px`. When the size of the viewport is greater than `769px` all works as expected. I'm using Bulma `.tile` and `.box`. I understand that this is some kind of conflict with a media query for the .tile element but I'm unable to figure out what it is. Thanks!
Codepen: https://codepen.io/albertrf147/pen/OqOJqG?editors=1100

```
<section class="section is-white has-text-centered">
    <div class="container is-narrow">
      <h1 class="title">My Projects</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">Here is some of my work, which I'm most proud of.</h2>

      <div class="tile is-ancestor">

        <div class="tile is-4 is-vertical is-parent">

          <div id="project-1" class="tile is-child box is-vertical-center is-paddingless project">
            <div class="project-title">CodePen</div>
            <div class="project-desc">
              <p class="project-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at rem numquam. Eveniet eos quae delectus et minus, eligendi, architecto ex sint assumenda saepe ut. Laborum unde possimus in voluptatum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="project-2" class="tile is-child box is-vertical-center is-paddingless project">
            <div class="project-title">Glitch</div>
            <div class="project-desc">
              <p class="project-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at rem numquam. Eveniet eos quae delectus et minus, eligendi, architecto ex sint assumenda saepe ut. Laborum unde possimus in voluptatum.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tile is-parent">
          <div id="project-3" class="tile is-child box is-vertical-center is-paddingless project">
            <div class="project-title">Another</div>
            <div class="project-desc">
              <p class="project-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis at rem numquam. Eveniet eos quae delectus et minus, eligendi, architecto ex sint assumenda saepe ut. Laborum unde possimus in voluptatum.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div></section>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat");
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css");

* {
  font-family: "Montserrat" !important;
}

body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.hero-foot img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.list {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.container.is-narrow {
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.skills {
  margin-top: -200px;
}

.tile.is-child {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.is-child.box {
  background-size: cover;
}

#project-1 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/449627/pexels-photo-449627.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beach-beautiful-bridge-449627.jpg&fm=jpg");
}

#project-2 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/97077/pexels-photo-97077.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=ai-codes-coding-97077.jpg&fm=jpg");
}

#project-3 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/5836/yellow-metal-design-decoration.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=art-creative-creativity-5836.jpg&fm=jpg");
}

.project {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.project-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  //background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.project:hover .project-title {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.project-desc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-align: justify;
  //border-radius: 5px;
  color: transparent;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  //visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.project:hover .project-desc {
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.project-text {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

**Bulma css**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px), print
.tile.is-4 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
    width: 33.33333%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px), print
.tile:not(.is-child) {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.tile.is-vertical {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.tile.is-parent {
    padding: .75rem;
}
.tile {
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: block;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-negative: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    min-height: -webkit-min-content;
    min-height: -moz-min-content;
    min-height: min-content;
}
```

Comment: did you try to set from height: 2.5em; to height: 100% for .project-desc ?

Comment: Your codepen doesn't match your question. You have `height: 2.5em` and `width: 100%` for `.project-desc`. Please update your question & code to be more clear with what you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you set .project-desc {height:100%} instead of height:2.5em it will work

Comment: @CWSites .project-desc has `height: 2.5em` by default but it goes to 100% when .project is hovered.

Comment: I see, the issue is certainly with your media query, however I don't see your code for that. Notice that not only the height doesn't change but your animation for the size change isn't working either.

Comment: I got you, I don't really know why it's happening this weird issue, but I got you a solution, add 'min-height:200px;' below the height on the hover as well, it will fill the parent and also when the content is greater than 200px.

Comment: @IndPendent Good call but the transition is not triggering and hence this isn't behaving as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `position: absolute` in `.project-desc` class it will work. I'm answering based on your codepen link.

Answer (score 0):

The bulma `.tile` is not a flex container below `769w`. You may enforce the parent tile to be flex container by adding below code to your css. This doesn't affect anything else.

```
.tile.is-parent {
  display: flex;
}
```